# Sync Framework doesnt update local table when single field is changed

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, microsoft-sync-framework

i am using Sync Framework 2.1 to sync a client db with a server db, there are certain tables that the client uploads, and certain tables that it downloads from the server. this is so certain information is controlled centrally, i have created 2 provisions, 1 for the client to upload, and one for the client to download. this all works great when adding and removing data, i can share it between multiple clients fine.

my problem is, i have a field in a products table with is for a discount percent, this needs to be controlled centrally, so that the clients will grab the new values when they sync. if i change it on the server, the client register the change when i sync, but the field doesn't update.

is there something i need to do to make a single field update, as i said, it knows its a change.

also, i have created the provisions for each client using the client pc name, so they are all individual, is this the correct way ? or am i ok to use the same provision for each client ?

Answer (score 0):

if your client is detecting the change but does not get updated, check for error or conflict in ApplyChangeFailed event.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so i did just that, and i found that there was some conflicts, i have changed it now to have 3 provisions, 1 that uploads only, 1 that downloads only, and 1 that uploads and downloads, this got round the conflicts, it was down to the fact that i was downloading changes, and then uploading them. once i changed the tables that needed this to a download/upload provision, it worked fine.